# How can I fix this query that uses the IF statment into the WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into DB (I am using **MySql**) and I have the following problem trying to add an *IF** condition into this query:

```
SELECT
    LCZ1.id                                          AS localization_id,
    LCZ1.description                                 AS localization_description, 
    CNT.id                                           AS country_id,
    CNT.country_name                                 AS country_name,
    CNT.isActive                                     AS country_is_active,
    RGN.id                                           AS region_id,
    RGN.region_name                                  AS region_name,
    PRV.id                                           AS province_id,
    PRV.province_name                                AS province_name,
    DST.id                                           AS district_id, 
    DST.district_name                                AS district_name,
    SCT.id                                           AS sector_id,
    SCT.sector_name                                  AS sector_name

FROM Localization                                   AS LCZ1
LEFT JOIN Country                                   AS CNT
     ON LCZ1.country_id = CNT.id
LEFT JOIN Region                                    AS RGN
     ON LCZ1.region_id = RGN.id
LEFT JOIN Province                                  AS PRV
     ON LCZ1.province_id = PRV.id 
LEFT JOIN District                                  AS DST
     ON LCZ1.district_id = DST.id
LEFT JOIN Sector                                    AS SCT
     ON LCZ1.sector_id = SCT.id

WHERE
     (LCZ1.country_id = (SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5))

IF(LCZ2.country_id = 1)
BEGIN
    AND
        LCZ1.region_id is not null
END

IF(LCZ2.country_id = 2)
BEGIN
    AND
        LCZ1.province_id is not null

END
```

As you can see what I am tryin to do is have a different part of my **WHERE** condition that depends by the value of the **LCZ2.country_id** retrieved in this subquery:

```
SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5
```

What is wrong in my query? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: You should explain what logic  you want to implement.  Your code makes no sense because `LCZ2` is out of scope.

Comment: Many outer joins. Do you really expect to find localizations without a country, region, etc.? Why do you try to outer join country when you are only looking for localizations in the same country as localization 5? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an immediate fix to your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (LCZ1.country_id = (SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5)) AND
    (
        (LCZ1.country_id = 1 AND LCZ1.region_id IS NOT NULL) OR
        (LCZ1.country_id = 2 AND LCZ1.provice_id IS NOT NULL) OR
         LCZ1.country_id NOT IN (1, 2)
    )
```

There is probably a better way of writing this, maybe without the subquery.  If you can update your answer to better describe the problem, perhaps this answer can be simplified.

Comment: I can't believe this got upvoted (but I get the answer).  `LCZ2` is out-of-scope.  It is unclear what logic the OP wants to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Upvoted twice, actually.  I don't see a scope problem, but I have no doubt that you (or I) could write a much tighter query if we understood the problem/data better.

Comment: . . `LCZ2` is defined in the subquery.  It is not recognized in the rest of the `WHERE` clause which is outside the subquery (as per the original question).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see what you mean now, maybe my edit is what the OP wants.

Comment: . . Doubtful, because your query would return an error that `LCZ2` is not recognized.  I started to write the same answer -- but stopped when I realized that the alias is not defined.  I'm befuddled.  I really don't know what the OP intends.